# Flask: Dynamically generate page endpoints and content

Tags: python, flask

I have an array of objects like this

```
   class post:
    def __init__(self, title, content, date, author):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = date
        self.author = author

posts = [
    post("Post1", "Post 1 content", str(date.today()), "Bob")
    post("Post2", "Post 2 content", str(date.today()), "Bob")
    post("Post3", "Post 3 content", str(date.today()), "Bob")
]
```

How do I have dynamically generate pages with templates at mysite.com/Post1, mysite.com/Post2, etc.?

Comment: maybe find some tutorial which will explain it all  - it will be faster. ie. `route('/Post<number>')`

Comment: BTW: it is good rule to use `UpperCaseNames` for classes - `class Post` - because it helps to recognize class in code `posts = [ Post(..), Post(...), Post(...) ]` . But you could keep it also in dictionares instead in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you keep posts on list then you can use

```
@app.route('/Post<int:number>')
```

to get post from list using its index (number)

```
@app.route('/Post<int:number>')
def post(number):
    if number < 1 or number > len(posts):
        abort(404, "This Post doesn't exist")   

    data = posts[number-1]

    return render_template_string('''
{{ item.title }}<br/>
{{ item.content }}<br/>
{{ item.date }}<br/>
{{ item.author }}<br/>''', item=data)
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from datetime import date

class Post:
    def __init__(self, title, content, date, author):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = date
        self.author = author

posts = [
    Post("Post1", "Post 1 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
    Post("Post2", "Post 2 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
    Post("Post3", "Post 3 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
]

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data=posts
    return render_template_string('''
{% for item in items %}
<a href="/{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</a> OR 
<a href="{{ url_for('post', number=loop.index) }}">{{ item.title }}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}''', items=data)


@app.route('/Post<int:number>')
def post(number):
    if number < 1 or number > len(posts):
        abort(404, "This Post doesn't exist")   

    data = posts[number-1]

    return render_template_string('''
{{ item.title }}<br/>
{{ item.content }}<br/>
{{ item.date }}<br/>
{{ item.author }}<br/>''', item=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run() #debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would keep posts in dictionary

```
posts = {
    "Post1": Post("Post1", "Post 1 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
    "Post2": Post("Post2", "Post 2 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
    "Post3": Post("Post3", "Post 3 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
}
```

then you would use

```
@app.route('/<string:title>')
```

to get post from dictionary using title/key

```
@app.route('/<string:title>')
def post(title):
    if title not in posts:
         abort(404, "This Post doesn't exist")   
         
    data = posts[title]
    
    return render_template_string('''
{{ item.title }}<br/>
{{ item.content }}<br/>
{{ item.date }}<br/>
{{ item.author }}<br/>''', item=data)
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, abort
from datetime import date

class Post:
    def __init__(self, title, content, date, author):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = date
        self.author = author

posts = {
    "Post1": Post("Post1", "Post 1 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
    "Post2": Post("Post2", "Post 2 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
    "Post3": Post("Post3", "Post 3 content", str(date.today()), "Bob"),
}

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = posts
    return render_template_string('''
{% for key, item in items.items() %}
<a href="/{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</a> OR 
<a href="{{ url_for('post', title=item.title) }}">{{ item.title }}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}''', items=data)

@app.route('/<string:title>')
def post(title):
    if title not in posts:
         abort(404, "This Post doesn't exist")   
         
    data = posts[title]
    
    return render_template_string('''
{{ item.title }}<br/>
{{ item.content }}<br/>
{{ item.date }}<br/>
{{ item.author }}<br/>''', item=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run() #debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```